# Is there a mongoose-like library for front-end?

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I don't mean the front-end will contact the db directly. I just hope there is a tool to transform the high-level db operations to low-level http commands. Then the app server can deal with the db server accordingly.

```
import React from 'react'
import X from 'X'
class Demo extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={result:null}
        let schema=new X.Schema({title:String});
        this.model=X.model('blob',schema)
    }
    handleClick=()=>{
        this.model.create({titile:this.input.value}).then(()=>{
            this.setState({result:"new blog stored in the remote db successfully"})
        })
    }
    render(){
        return <div>
            <input ref=(input)=>{this.input=input} />
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>submit</button>
            <div>{this.state.result}</div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if something like this exists, and even if it didn't I would think it'd pose a huge security threat to the site.

However there are some good tools to create schema like queries from react to the backend.
Look into using [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/) as well as [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/), there are of course other tools and services but I find that these are the most popular ones and you'll find a lot of tutorials online on how to use them with react (such as [here](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/getting-started-with-react-and-graphql-395311c1e8da) and [here](https://medium.com/quick-code/how-to-integrate-react-redux-and-firebase-in-3-simple-steps-c44804a6af38))